# Comic where Kara and Kal-el are sent to Earth in pods, Kara comes late

Tags: superman, episode-identification, supergirl

What is the comic where both Kryptonians, Kara and Kal-el, are sent in pods to Earth; Kara's pod is hit by debris from Krypton exploding and goes off track and into cryo and ends up orbiting a star? (Phantom Zone maybe?)

She eventually makes it to Earth, expecting Kal-el to be a baby and he is grown. They fight and Batman tells him be careful after analyzing her strength (because of the star).

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like Supergirl's origin story from the ['New 52'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_52) comics.

Kal-el discusses the trajectory of her pod in [Supergirl Vol. 6 #12](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/SUPERGIRL_VOL_6_12)

[image]

Comment: Her origin is told over the whole series, starting with #0

Answer (score 1):

You may be recalling elements of Supergirl's 2004 reintroduction to post-Crisis continuity in *Superman / Batman #8* (May 2004).

[image]

Pre-Crisis Supergirl died during Crisis on Infinite Earths (the infamous cover #7) and Post-Crisis had "Matrix Supergirl" (a shapeshifting Supergirl impersonator of sorts).  However, writer Jeph Loeb made a concerted effort to begin to reintroduce Silver Age elements back into then-contemporary continuity.

Aligning with your question, Supergirl's return was marked by the age difference, fighting with the World's Finest, and seemingly stronger than Superman.

Some other notable things arising from that run was the exposed mid-driff, Dark Supergirl, the idea of Supergirl being "raised" by the Trinity and training on Themyscira with Wonder Woman's Amazons, and Supergirl being a difficult rebellious teen (compared to her more milquetoast Pre-Crisis personality also reflected in the 1984 film).

This arc was adapted into a 2010 animated feature, *[Superman/Batman: Apocalypse](https://youtu.be/di9SPw_7-88)* which was generally well received, successful, and many people's introduction to this version of Supergirl.